# Last cell in row and column in Epplus - C#

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to select a range from the first to the last cell filled in the row or column. In VBA the code stays as below using xlDown or xlToRight.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
```

How could I do it the same way in C # using Epplus?
I will start from cell B139 and I must go to the last row and column

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An important thing to know about the Cells object in an Worksheet in EPPlus is that it contains only references to cell that have data added to it. So with a little bit of LINQ you can get the address of every "Row" like this:

```
var lastRowCell1 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Row == 1);

var lastRowCell2 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Row == 2);

var lastColCell1 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Column == 1);

var lastColCell2 = worksheet.Cells.Last(c => c.Start.Column == 2);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use linq like this with the excel interop library?

Answer (score 12):

To get the last Cell's index you can use `worksheet.Dimension`:

```
int numCol = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
int numCol = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
```

If you want the last address of Column or Row you can use this:

```
String lastAddress = worksheet.Dimension.Address.Last().ToString();
```