# Insert into Existing excel file using EPP on C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to insert value on my excel ,but i have a problem when i run my application, its create a new file excel ,doesnt insert value into existing file,

```html
  using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
              {
                  excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet1");
                  // Target a worksheet
var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Worksheet1"];

    
                  worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Name";
                  worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "ID";

                  FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(@"E:\ExcelTest.xls");
                  excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
```

I want my Program insert into existing file ,not create a new one,

how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EPPlus Wiki Getting Started](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) covered this exact scenario.

```
FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(@"E:\ExcelTest.xls");
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
{
      // Target a worksheet
      var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Worksheet1"];
      worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Name";
      worksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "ID";
      excel.Save();
}
```

Comment: but i have a problem about how to get the last row of the opened excel file,
 i want my code like this

worksheet.Cells[last_row, 1].Value = "Name";

can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558303/last-cell-in-row-and-column-in-epplus-c-sharp/42678543

Comment: @RickiFernando https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers